# Issues with Jquery ".append" in IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-plugins

well, i've been having problems trying to use the ".append" in IE8, my code works fine in all browsers (even IE9), but I'm having issues with IE8.. Here's my code:

```
    divLine = null
    for(var i = ini; i < fim; i++ ){
       if(i % 5 === 0){
           var divLine = $("<div class='line' style='float:left;display:block;padding-top:25px;'></div>")
           $("#products").append(divLine)
       }
       if (linkI[i] != "semLink") {
       if (i != (4 + ini) && i != (9 + ini) && i != (14 + ini) && i != (19 + ini)) { 
          divLine.append("<div id='" + albuns[i] + "'style='float:left;display:block;'>" + 
         "<a href='" + url[i] + "'>" +
         "<img src='" + imagesUrl[i] + "' width='170' />" + "</a>" +
 "<div style='width:170px;'>" +
    "<h3 class='shout bare mts'>" +
       "<b>" + names[i] + "</b>" +
    "</h3>" + 
    "<h6 class='mbs'>" + 
        albuns[i] + 
    "</h6>" +
       "<a class='icons-comprar lfloat mtxs mrs' href='" + linkS[i] + "' target='_blank' >Comprar </br></a>" + 
        "<a class='icons-itunesSmall lfloat mtm' href='" + linkI[i] + "' target='_blank'>Itunes</a>" + 
  "</div>" + 
  "</div>" + 
    "<img src='http://assets.jumpseller.com/store/biscoitofino/themes/8055/space.png' width='30' style='float:left;display:block;'/>" +      
         "</div>")
          } else {
             divLine.append("<div id='" + albuns[i] + "' style='float:left;display:block;'>" + 
         "<a href='" + url[i] + "'>" +
         "<img src='" + imagesUrl[i] + "' width='170' />" +
"</a>" +
 "<div style='width:170px;'>" +
"<h3 class='shout bare mts'>" +
  "<b>" + names[i] + "</b>" +
"</h3>" + 
"<h6 class='mbs'>" + 
        albuns[i] + 
"</h6>" +
  "<a class='icons-comprar lfloat mtxs mrs' href='" + linkS[i] + "' target='_blank' >Comprar </br></a>" + 
  "<a class='icons-itunesSmall lfloat mtm' href='" + linkI[i] + "' target='_blank'>Itunes</a>" + 
         "</div>")
          }
      } else {
          if (i != (4 + ini) && i != (9 + ini) && i != (14 + ini) && i != (19 + ini)) {
          divLine.append("<div id='" + albuns[i] + "' style='float:left;display:block;'>" + 
         "<a href='" + url[i] + "'>" +
         "<img src='" + imagesUrl[i] + "' width='170' />" +
"</a>" +
 "<div style='width:170px;'>" +
"<h3 class='shout bare mts'>" +
  "<b>" + names[i] + "</b>" +
"</h3>" + 
"<h6 class='mbs'>" + 
        albuns[i] + 
"</h6>" +
  "<a class='icons-comprar lfloat mtxs mrs' href='" + linkS[i] + "' target='_blank' >Comprar </br></a>" + 
  "</div>" + 
  "</div>" + 
    "<img src='http://assets.jumpseller.com/store/biscoitofino/themes/8055/space.png' width='30' style='float:left;display:block;'/>" +      
         "</div>")
          } else {
            divLine.append("<div id='" + albuns[i] + "' style='float:left;display:block;'>" + 
         "<a href='" + url[i] + "'>" +
         "<img src='" + imagesUrl[i] + "' width='170' />" +
"</a>" +
 "<div style='width:170px;'>" +
"<h3 class='shout bare mts'>" +
  "<b>" + names[i] + "</b>" +
"</h3>" + 
"<h6 class='mbs'>" + 
        albuns[i] + 
"</h6>" +
  "<a class='icons-comprar lfloat mtxs mrs' href='" + linkS[i] + "' target='_blank' >Comprar </br></a>" + 
  "</div>" + 
  "</div>" + 
         "</div>")  
          }
      }
 }
```

in which:

```
 albuns = new Array();
 imagesUrl = new Array();
 url = new Array();
 names = new Array();
 linkS = new Array();
 linkI = new Array();
```

are already sorted arrays generated by a server.
I also took printscreens of the output in both chrome and IE8:
IE8 below:
[image]
Chrome below:
[image]

As we can notice the output in IE is completely distorted...
here's the site in question:
http://biscoitofino.jumpseller.com/catalogo

Any suggestions???
Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm going to bet it's because you were missing a closing tag somewhere in the big code you posted

Comment: maybe... funny thing is that it work fine in all browsers i've tested so far..

Comment: So if it works fine.. what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Working with IE.. if you are missing any closing tags.. it will break.. so go back and make sure you are closing all the tags in your code

Comment: Did you check if it gives any messages in it's error console? (<kbd>F12</kbd>, Script tab)

Comment: `.innerHTML` is allowed to gag on bad HTML -- one of the better reasons not to use it.  (The jQuery method you use actually uses .innerHTML internally.)  If you are going to use the beast, it is a lot simpler if you build small pieces and connect them, rather than a mega-line blob like you are now.  Makes tracking the syntax MUCH easier.

Comment: Guys I've just fixed it, i think the problem was not with missign any closing tags, the problem was the excess of closing Tags xD  it's working fine now, Thank you guys, and good night